# Why does big script of inserts take forever to run on just this one server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

One of our users deleted about 17000 rows out of a table.  We restored the database and quickly scripted the insert statements to put it back.  The way it was scripted is one insert statement per row.  I understand that this isn't necessarily the best way to do it but it is what it is.  These statements took about 30 seconds to run in the development and production environments.  However, it took around 15 minutes in the test environment.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temptable;

CREATE TABLE #temptable (
[IntField1] INT
,[IntField2] INT
,[VarcharField1] VARCHAR(70)
,[VarcharField2] VARCHAR(100)
,[VarcharField3] VARCHAR(4)
,[IntField3] INT
,[IntField4] INT
,[DatetimeField1] DATETIME2(2)
,[DatetimeField2] DATETIME2(2)
);

INSERT INTO #temptable ([fields]....)
VALUES ([values]....);
ad nauseam...
```

1. The dev and test environments are configured the same as far as I have looked (ram, cpu, maxdop, cost threshold, etc).
2. It does not matter what database I am in when testing this.  It inserts into a temp table first.  I've tested in master, tempdb, and different user databases.
3. It doesn't matter if I change it to a regular table either.
4. When running an extended event trace on it I do see quite a bit of SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits but when watching the CPUs, none of them even get close to 100%.
5. When looking at the trace I see a sql_statement_completed for the "DROP TABLE..." statement and then a bunch of SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits and then the sql_statement_starting for the "CREATE TABLE..." and time between the completed and starting is 1.8 seconds.

When I run the script with SET STATISTICS TIME ON I get the following
Highlighting just the DROP, CREATE and 10 inserts.  Average Insert time looks like this.

Highlighting just the DROP, CREATE and 300 inserts.  Average Insert time looks like this.

```
(1 row affected)
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
    CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
    CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 32 ms.
```

Highlighting just the DROP, CREATE and 400 inserts.  Average Insert time looks like this.

```
(1 row affected)
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 40 ms.
```

Highlighting just the DROP, CREATE and 700 inserts.  Average Insert time looks like this (can go as high as 100ms).

```
(1 row affected)
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
    CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
    CPU time = 63 ms,  elapsed time = 69 ms.
```

Highlighting just the DROP, CREATE and 4700 inserts.  Average Insert time looks like this (Goes as high at 1000ms multiple times).

```
(1 row affected)
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
    CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
    CPU time = 469 ms,  elapsed time = 488 ms.
```

And then there's this:
Comment out everything after the first 10 insert statements but run the entire 35000 line script (times can go to 3000 ms).

```
(1 row affected)
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
    CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 2 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
    CPU time = 1859 ms,  elapsed time = 1920 ms.
```

So my question is, WHAT AM I MISSING?  It is obviously something with this set of servers but I don't know what else to look at.  It also seems to be related to the size of the script itself.

Comment: If you're trying to run 4,700 insert statements in a single batch, you are probably running up against SQL Server's ability to keep up with logging all of those individual statements, and then eventually checkpoint will come into play, and possibly other background behavior (like VDI). Instead of a 35,000 line script containing 4,700 individual insert statements, I would probably convert your script to use BULK INSERT (or at least plan to prepare a better script _next time_, maybe VALUES(1000 rows at a time), because I assume you're done and aren't going to do it again for this specific task).

Comment: As a TL;DR, I would simply never try to run a script in SSMS that had 35,000 lines. You've got to break it up one way or another.

Comment: When I see SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD in our environment, I immediately suspect a virus scan on the file for a sparse snapshot.  For example, when DBCC runs it create a snapshot.  In our case, the snapshot file was very small.  However, the scan needed to materialize the bits to scan - 2x the original file IO.  This caused our timeout.  There are so many possibilities to explain one server being slower.  In one case, one of our test VMs had a CPU config corruption and was 1/10 a normal CPU.  After much angst, we built a new VM.

Comment: @AaronBertran I completely agree.  I know you've heard this before but I didn't write this.  :D  It was just weird that it ran in 30secs in 2 environments and 15+ minutes in another.  I was trying to figure out the difference in case this is a symptom of a bigger underlying issue.